# URL MANIPULATION WHEN CHECKED

Tags: javascript, url

I am using the following code

```js
$checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox');
$checkboxes.change(function() {
    window.location.hash = 'a=' + $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(",");
    console.log(window.location.hash);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="one">one<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="two">two<br>
```

And the output is `#a=one,two`

But I am looking for `?a=one,two`

Comment: So you should not be setting the hash, you should be using `history.pushState`

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: What did not work?

Comment: @samuelkomera try ```window.location.search``` instead of ```window.location.hash```

Comment: I tried it but it only takes one checkbox at a time the next one is not appending to it